# JavaScript Css Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a Javascript animation at http://dev17.edreamz3.com/css/

All code works, however, there are performance problems. on Desktop, its good, On mobile things are so slow that it's unusable. I want to optimize the animation so that it runs smoothly on mobile. It can take 20 seconds or more for the animation to render.

Right now the way the code is designed is in js/anim.js there is a render() function that gets executed every time a scroll event happens. The problem is that this routine is not efficient, that's what I think of. Each time render() executes it loops through all the paths and sections of the maze and redraws them, is there any alternative way or a strategy to get it working both on mobile as well as desktop.

```
var offPathTime = 1000;
window.offSection = -1;
function render() {
    // var top = ($window.scrollTop() + (0.4 * $window.height())) / window.scale;
    var top = ($('.parent-div').scrollTop() + (0.4 * $('.parent-div').height())) / window.scale;
    top -= 660;
    top /= mazeSize.h;

    if (window.offSection != -1) {
        $body.addClass("blockScroll");
        $('.parent-div').addClass("blockScroll");
        // var wtop = $window.scrollTop() / window.scale;
        var wtop = $('.parent-div').scrollTop() / window.scale;
        wtop -= 660;
        wtop /= mazeSize.h;

        var $offSection = $("#offSection" + window.offSection);
        var $section = $("#section" + window.offSection);

        $(".section").removeClass("sectionActive");
        $offSection.addClass("sectionActive");
        $section.addClass("sectionActive");

        var sTop = 200 -(mazeSize.h * (window.offSections[window.offSection].cy - wtop));
        $container.animate({
            left: 290 -(mazeSize.w * window.offSections[window.offSection].cx) + "px",
            top: sTop + "px"
        }, offPathTime);

        // Path
        var lr = offPaths[window.offSection].x1 > offPaths[window.offSection].x0;
        var dx = Math.abs(offPaths[window.offSection].x1 - offPaths[window.offSection].x0);
        var dashw = (dx * mazeSize.w) | 0;

        $offPaths[window.offSection].css("width", "0px");
        $offPaths[window.offSection].show();
        if (lr) {
            $offPaths[window.offSection].animate({
                width: dashw + "px"
            }, offPathTime);
        } else {
            var x0 = offPaths[window.offSection].x0 * mazeSize.w;
            var x1 = offPaths[window.offSection].x1 * mazeSize.w;
            $offPaths[window.offSection].css("left", x0 + "px");
            $offPaths[window.offSection].animate({
                width: dashw + "px",
                left: x1 + "px"
            }, offPathTime);
        }

        return;
    }
    $body.removeClass("blockScroll");
    $('.parent-div').removeClass("blockScroll");
    $(".offPath").hide();
    if ($container.css("top") != "0px") {
        $container.animate({
                left: "-1550px",
                top: "0px"
            }, 500);
    }

    var pathIdx = -1;
    var path0 = paths[0];
    var path1;
    var inPath = 0;
    var i;
    var curTop = 0;
    var found = false;
    for (i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
        var top0 = (i == 0) ? 0 : paths[i-1].y;
        var top1 = paths[i].y;

        if (top >= top0 && top < top1) {
            pathIdx = i;
            path1 = paths[i];
            inPath = (top - top0) / (top1 - top0);
            found = true;
            if (i > 0) {
                var dy = paths[i].y - paths[i-1].y;
                var dx = paths[i].x - paths[i-1].x;
                var vert = dx == 0;

                if (vert)
                    $paths[i-1].css("height", (dy * mazeSize.h * inPath) + "px");
                $paths[i-1].show();
            }
        } else if (top >= top0) {
            path0 = paths[i];
            var dy = paths[i].y - top0;
            var vert = dy != 0;

            if (i > 0) {
                if (vert)
                    $paths[i-1].css("height", (dy * mazeSize.h) + "px");
                $paths[i-1].show();
            }
        } else {
            if (i > 0) {
                $paths[i-1].hide();
            }
        }

        curTop = top1;
    }

    // Check for an active section
    $(".section").removeClass("sectionActive");
    var section;
    for (i=0; i<sections.length; i++) {
        var d = Math.abs(sections[i].cy - (top - 0.05));
        if (d < 0.07) {
            var $section = $("#section" + i);
            $section.addClass("sectionActive");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tested in my desktop and see lags, nor working in first time. in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) At the very least - assign all DOM objects to variables outside of the function scope. Like this:

```
var $parentDiv = $('.parent-div');
var $sections = $(".section");
...
function render() {
   ...
```

2) Also you should probably stop animation before executing it again, like this:

```
$container.stop(true).animate({ 
   ...
```

If you are running render() function on scroll - it will run many times per second. stop() helps to prevent it somewhat.

3) If it will not be sufficient - you can switch from jQuery to [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/)(jQuery-like api, but much faster and uses css transitions for animations) or to [Velocity](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)(basically drop-in replacement for jQuery $.animate and much faster than original) or even to [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) - much more work obviously, but it is very fast and featured animation library.